# How to debug git source code?

Tags: git, debugging, merge

I'm currently working on a project that needs to change the source code of git. I want to change the source code because when you setup a merge driver, git always runs it's diff algorithm first, but the git diff algorithm doesn't detects some conflicts that my merge tool detects.

So, I need to change the source code in order that git always uses my merge tool. To do that, I need to have a better understanding about the git merge code workflow, but reading million lines of git's source code is not an option. I need to compile and debug the git source code, but I have no idea of which is the better way and how to do it.

Please Help :)

Comment: It is extraordinarily unlikely that you need to modify Git itself to accomplish this, particularly because Git was designed with this exact use case in mind. Please explain how [`git mergetool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool) does not satisfy your needs.

Comment: The merge tool that we developed is based in the semistructured merge concept (i.e detects conflicts via syntax tree, not via text difference like unstructured merge tools). The merge tool is called when git detects conflicts through its diff algorithm (which is based on the unstructured merge) and this algorithm doesn't detect conflicts that our merge tool detects. So we need to always use our merge tool

Comment: Oh, I see - that's definitely a more unusual use case. Does also setting `git difftool` help? (I assume that your merge tool can be adapted to report this). Barring that you may have to reach out to the mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org) to get a good idea of how to do this.

Comment: Maybe, I was thinking of setting a custom "fake" diff driver that always report conflicts, so that our merge tool can always get and analyze the incoming merge data. Thank you very much @Pockets !

Answer (score 0):

So, after a time, I figured out how to solve my problem without messing around with the git source code. What I have done?

- My main problem was that the git diff algorithm doesn't find some conflicts that the semistructured merge tool that we created can find. So, to solve that I've created a custom fake diff driver so that my merge tool is always called to analyze the currente merge.

To do that, I edited the .gitconfig file and added this fake diff driver:

`[diff "fake"]
 command = false`

That solves my problem, because now the merge driver is always called :)